# How to put an comma after 2 characters (counting from the right) in the whole column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a question about a function in Excel.
So I want to put a comma in the second position on the right by all the numbers (So the whole column). I just can't find it anywhere on the internet, so maybe you guys can't help.

In the picture you see the upper one as a example of how I want it to be. There are more than 50k lines so I don't want to do it manually.

A picture of the situation :

[image]

Comment: Do you have a decimal comma in your locale? If so, you may use `=IF(A1>99,A1/100,A1)`.

Comment: If you're trying to divide them by 100, enter 100 in a cell, copy it, then select the number cells and use paste special, divide.

Comment: @JvdV , @Rory The only thing I want to do is place a comma after 2 numbers (starting from right) I don`t want to divide them, just want to put a character(in this case a comma "," in between the numbers because it is for prices.

Comment: Format cells as `#,#0`?